# Axios Interceptor always return 403 on Post Requests

Tags: vuejs3, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm currently developing an Website and using an AxiosInterceptor for sending an JWT with every request. Currently I'm always getting an 403 on Post-Request, only on Post-Request. Eg. Trying to start a method in the backend.

I have already an PostMapping where i get an 409 as an answer. But i did the same one the other, but getting an 403, does someone have an Idea?

Comment: [403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) "_indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it_".  In other words, your backend denies your frontend request due to lack of (or wrong) authorization.  You should confirm the authorization flow for your request is correct.  If you need help, you'll need to post more details and some code, ideally enough for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.